# Como mando mi archivo SSL en un url en dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, certificado-ssl

tengo una consulta. Resulta que estamos haciendo una app donde se podra hacer transferencia bancaria. ahora el banco ya me paso todas las credenciales y lo probe en potsman y todo esta bien en potsman tambien tuve que subir el archivo SSL que el banco me dio.

yo la primera vez queria probarlo llamando al servicio que el banco me proporciono como lo hacia con otros servicios comunes y corrientes asi:

```
respuesta = await http.post( urlSandBox,
          
          body: bodyEncoded,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Correlation-Id" : "4",
            "Authorization" : "....."
          }
         );
```

Ademas esta llamada entra por el `catch(e){ print(e.toString) }` pero no me muestra ningun error y mi parecer esque me falta enviar el certificado que les comento.

pero la verdad no tengo ni idea de donde meter el archivo SSL que el banco me paso y aparte poner su contraseña (la contraseña del certificado me la dieron en forma de texto no es otro archivo ni nada)
el archivo tiene extension .pfx

Muchas gracias amigos.

Comment: El archivo no se envía. Lee sobre cómo funciona el cifrado asimétrico, que si lo configuras mal terminas con problemas serios de seguridad

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardar el certificado como un activo, necesitas usar `SecurityContext` para agregar un certificado.

> ```
> SecurityContext serverContext = new SecurityContext()
>   ..useCertificateChain('path/to/my_cert.pem')
>   ..usePrivateKey('path/to/my_key.pem'),
>                   password: 'my_key_password');
>
> var server = await HttpServer.bindSecure('example.com',
>                               portNumber, // usually, 443
>                               serverContext,
>                               backlog: 5);
> ```

Revisar la documentación aquí https://dart-lang.github.io/server/tls-ssl.html